# Using a MySQL database to fill php arrays

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a PHP script designed to answer a users question. Currently I use arrays to provide the programmed questions and then echo the answer for that question. Instead, **I want the script to search a MySQL database for questions and their answer. How can I do this in PHP?**

I hope you can understand my question.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if(stripos($_GET['q'],'what is my ip')===0){
    echo "Your IP address is <b>{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}</b>";
}

?>

<form method='get' action=''>
<input type='text' name='q'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best bet is start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and learn how to connect to a mysql database and execute queries against it. Of course you will need to create the database, tables and populate the data, before you can retrieve anything.

Comment: Ok, please update your question to be a little more specific, do you need to know what kind of query to write, or how to process the results of the query? show us what your tables/data looks like, etc.